# Reading XML elements to ListView - how do i pass both variables to method

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listview, linq-to-xml

I've got a simple XML file from which i need to extract the inner text of 2 of the elements and pass them to a method which lists the text in 2 columns of a ListView. I'e got it working so that it extracts the text from 1 of the elements, but i'm struggling to understand how i get it to populate the second column with data from the second element.

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Projects>
  <Project>
    <ProjectName>Test project1</ProjectName>
    <ProjectType>MSWORD</ProjectType>
  </Project>
  <Project>
    <ProjectName>MyNewProject</ProjectName>
    <ProjectType>SGML</ProjectType>
  </Project>
  <Project>
    <ProjectName>NewProject3</ProjectName>
    <ProjectType>XML</ProjectType>
  </Project>
  <Project>
    <ProjectName>Jake'sProject</ProjectName>
    <ProjectType>SGML</ProjectType>
  </Project>
  <Project>
    <ProjectName>P3_test</ProjectName>
    <ProjectType>SGML</ProjectType>
  </Project>
</Projects>
```

The method which loads and extracts the elements:

```
private void openProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Projects myProjects = new Projects(this); 

    myProjects.Show(); //displays the Form 2 (called Projects)

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load("O:\\TestDaws\\projects.xml");

    string projList = "/Projects/Project";

    XmlNodeList xname = xdoc.SelectNodes(projList + "/ProjectName");
    XmlNodeList xtype = xdoc.SelectNodes(projList + "/ProjectType");

    foreach (XmlNode xNodeName in xname)
    {
        myProjects.buildProjectList(xNodeName.InnerText.ToString());
    }
}
```

And finally the mehod in my second form which builds the listView:

```
public void buildProjectList(string project)
{
    ListViewItem projItem = new ListViewItem(project);

   // projItem.SubItems.Add("--");
    listView1.Items.Add(projItem);
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how i achieve this? I can see that i'm only passing one of the elements (xname) into the method in the second form. But how do i pass the other in? Have a separate foreach? What i need to be able to do is pass both xname and xtype variables into the method in the second form, but i don't know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.itemof.aspx) defined on [`XmlNodeList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) so you can use a simple for:

```
for (int i=0; i<xname.Count; i++)
{
   XmlNode xNodeName = xname[i];
   XmlNode xNodeType = xtype[i];

   myProjects.buildProjectList(xNodeName.InnerText.ToString(), 
                               xNodeType.InnerText.ToString());
}
```

This code assumes that the `xname` and `xtype` lists will always be parallel.

Of course, you should change the `buildProjectList` to something like:

```
public void buildProjectList(string project, string type)
{
    ListViewItem projItem = new ListViewItem(project+"-"+type);

    listView1.Items.Add(projItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution this is also safer since you don't have the types and names in different array's

```
XmlNodeList xprojects = xdoc.SelectNodes(projList);

foreach (XmlNode xProject in xprojects)
{
    string projectname = "";
    string projecttype = "";
    foreach(XmlNode xProjectAttr in xProject){
        switch(xProjectAttr.Name){
            case "ProjectName":
                projectname = xProjectAttr.Value;
                break;
            case "ProjectType":
                projecttype = xProjectAttr.Value;
                break;
        }
    }
    myProjects.buildProjectList(projectname,type);
}
```

and your other function will be

```
public void buildProjectList(string project,string type)
{
   ListViewItem projItem = new ListViewItem(project);

   projItem.SubItems.Add(type);
   listView1.Items.Add(projItem);
}
```

**EDIT**

I edited a bit. Im not good with XPath so I think that was the problem and with this setup if you miss a ProjectType or ProjectName it will continue without one and now throw exceptions

Comment: This seems like a good solution. However, i'm getting a NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
This exception is thrown in the foreach loop. How can i get around this please?

Comment: @user2008060 oh sorry, XmlNode is not my thing tbh let me edit it so it works I hope :)

Comment: @user2008060 I edited it, if it doesn't work I will look into it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

In [EaterOfCorpses's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872956/2134311) change the following, it will work

```
XmlNodeList xprojects = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Project");

projectname = xProjectAttr.InnerText;
projecttype = xProjectAttr.InnerText;
```